# How to determine the php json_encode objects

Tags: php, json

I am trying to parse a big and -at least for me- a messy  json file, I get the following error all the time: "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object...".

My question is that: is there any way that can help in determining what are the generated objects after the json_encode() function processes the json content?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `$var = json_decode($data)` and dumping the $var? I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: Show your code. I feel like you're decoding it as an array and trying to access it as an object...